# What does my simple code/class do

Tags: java, class

Iam trying to figure out how classes work, for some reason I just dont get it at all no matter how many times I read my java book.. I created this class and then I tried to call it ( is it called call?)

```
public class ovn7a {

    int []vektor;

public ovn7a () {

for(int k=1; k<10; k++){
vektor[k]=0+k;
System.out.println(vektor[k]);
}
```

And then in another window I have this

```
public class test1 {
public static void main(String []args) {
ovn7a hej = new ovn7a(); }}
```

So what I think was gonna happen is I create a vektor. Then in the constructor there's a for function that gives slot 1-10 a number. I realise that I havnt named or told how many total slots the vektor has, I dont know where to do this when creating a class. Normally I would just

> write int []vektor = new int[20];

but with class.. ye i dunno wtf to do.

Anyway what I thought would happen when I run this class from my other "file", I thought I would take everything thats in my constructor from the class, copy it or something and name it hej. So I thought it would now do whats in the constructor, it would create numbers and put it in the vektor and then print it out, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

In your class ovn7a, the for loop has no } on the end to close it. This is what it should look like. Also, I have renamed the class Ovn7a (it's a java convention that you begin class names with a capital letter).

```
public class Ovn7a {

    int []vektor;

    public ovn7a () {

        for(int k=1; k<10; k++){
        vektor[k]=0+k;
        System.out.println(vektor[k]);}  //this } is what you are missing
    }
}
```

When you create your own instance of the class (by typing Ovn7a hej = new Ovn7a() ) then it runs the code in the constructor which is where your for loop is.

Also, what you have there isn't a vector object. It is an array which has been named "vektor".
You have named the array. You then need to instantiate it and give it some values. So add this line at the top of the constructor:

```
vektor = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

Comment: Since the vektor variable gets it's values set in the loop, you can just declare the array as follows: `int[] vektor = new int[10];`

Comment: There is also no reason to set vektor[k] to 0 + k.  Adding 0 to any integer is redundant.